# Best transform of matrix to make it efficient for shift-then-invert?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerics, eigenvalues

I am using ARPACK to find the smallest eigenvalue of a matrix. I use the shift and invert method. That is, looking for the largest eigenvalue of
$$
(A-\sigma I)^{-1}.
$$
However, I do not know $\sigma$ beforehand and have to adjust its value during the iteration process. Therefore, I need to do compute $(A-\sigma I)^{-1}v$ for many $v$ and several $\sigma.$

I am wondering what algorithm can write $A$ into a form where $A-\sigma I$ is very easy to invert. $LU, QR$ factorisation does not work. Hessenberg decomposition works but is much slower. Can anyone propose a good solution?

Comment: @hardmath Yes. Please assume that?

Comment: If you are trying to find several eigenvalue/eigenvector pairs, you are ordinarily advised not to try and rewrite the many fine library packages that already exist.  In another post you revealed in the Comments that a matrix was positive definite, an important consideration.  Please revise this Question to supply more details for what you want to do, what properties $A$ has, and what accuracy is needed for eigenvalues (or eigenvectors, if that is important).

Comment: @hardmath I do not understand why you say that. I am using an existing library. It is not a rewrite. Why do you think positive definiteness helps solving the problem? I will add the detail when I find out it is important, but at this moment feel free to make additional assumptions. (This is not an exam question!)

Comment: @hardmath The reason why I do not provide too much details is that I do not want to add distractions. For example, you can explain to me why I should add the positive definiteness condition. Why and how is that going to help?

Comment: For instance if $A$ were symmetric positive definite, then its smallest eigenvalue is the reciprocal of the largest eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: @hardmath But that is not related to this question I am asking here, so I am not mentioning it. It is related to my other question, so I mention it there.

Comment: You have asked me to *assume* $A$ is symmetric, and to explain regarding positive definiteness, why "and how is that going to help."  I've done so, but instead of clarifying the Question as to symmetry and positive definiteness, you now say "that is not related to this Question."  Recall that you opened your post with "I am using ARPACK to find the smallest eigenvalue of a matrix."  I'm not willing to analyze your needs further without some cooperation on your part.